# HTML 5 Validator does not like CSS Embedded in Body

Tags: html, css

> Error Line 16, Column 23: Element style not allowed as child of
>   element body in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this
>   subtree.)

Because it sais "in this context" I'm hoping there is a way to embed CSS my HTML 5 using

```
<style TYPE="text/css">
</style>
```

and a different "context" whatever that means.

I have all my code in neat HTML 5 / CSS modules...and I prefer not to split up my CSS from my HTML though I think most people do it this way.

Is there a way I can keep embedded CSS w/ my HTML 5 and not break validation.

If not can I put the embedded CSS in the Head of the document?

Where can I put it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you use external stylesheets?

Comment: Not sure what your last sentence is trying to say. Why can't you put it in the document head?

Comment: Why do you care about the validity of your document during development stages? If you're that concerned, you may as well put it in the head where it belongs, and live with scrolling up and down your document or cloning the editor window.

Comment: More importantly I'd like to understand why this restriction is put on CSS when it works just the same.

Comment: That would probably be because [styles are considered a kind of metadata for HTML documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3), rather than the content that is displayed itself.

Comment: The reason is mostly what BoltClock said, and partly because no one has found a use case for having document wide CSS in the body. On the other hand, for blocks of markup within the page, having CSS dedicated for that only, has been identified as a useful thing to have. For that `<style scoped>` is being invented, but it is currently a work in progress and has no implementations yet. `<style scoped>` will be allowed in body.

Comment: @Alochi, BoltClock - A use case would be that I can use CSS/HTML modules...this allow me to keep my variables close together and also keeps my code modular.  CSS and HTML are separate languages but they still logically go together in modules that I can move around as needed...for example I can copy paste one module into a fiddle...and insert it back in my code base when I'm done updating it...does that sound like a use case to you.  Also the fact that minification for CSS/HTML is far less then javascript is this separation of variables.  Mabye someone will build a minifier that can minify...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `style` tag goes in the `head` tag unless the `scoped` attribute is present, e.g.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5 CSS scope attribute</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

<style>
.myClass {
    color: red;
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div>
<span class="myClass">This text is red, and the background is blue.</span>
</div>

<div>
<style scoped>
.myClass {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
<span class="myClass">This text is red, and the background is yellow.</span>
</div>

</body>
```

However, the `scoped` attribute is not implemented in any browser yet:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/the-style-element.html#the-style-element

Comment: After 2 years, Except Firefox, none of the browsers implemented scoped attribute. And it seems like other browsers won't implement this feature. http://caniuse.com/style-scoped

Answer (score 4):

The style tag is only allowed within the head section.

That or as inline styles right with the tags, which you should only do if you have good reason to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike the `<script>` tag, `<style>` can be used only in `<head>` section. That's why you're getting the error. Put it between the `<head></head>` tags.

---

However, you still can use style in body and still have a **valid** code, but in a bit different way. You must put it in the `style` attribute of an element.

Example:

```
<span style="background-color: #000; color: #fff;">Some text here</span>
```

That's the only way if you want your code to be valid. You can't use `<style></style>` **tags**, only **attributes**.

Answer (score 3):

The validator’s error message is in error, if you have the `style` element at the very start of the `body` element, as I suspect it is. As the explanation of the message implies, such a construct is allowed, provided that the `scoped` attribute is used.

Using the `scoped` attribute is pointless, since no browsers implements it yet, but if you use it, future browsers may interpret the element quite differently from current browsers. So the above is just the formal side of the matter.

A simple `style` element without attributes works in browsers even when placed in the `body`. The formal rules just forbid it, and HTML5 currently sticks to it, simply because its editor thinks that the use cases presented are not significant.

However, it is better to put the `style` element inside the `head` element, where it is valid by all specs. (The need for putting it in `body` normally arises only when an author has no control over `head` but can inject code into `body`.)

The wording “in this context”, used by the validator in some situations, is admittedly confusing. I think it results from some change that I proposed long ago, to avoid even worse (misleading) formulations. The wording is meaningful e.g. if the markup is

```
<div>
foo
<style scoped></style>
</div>
```

which is wrong by HTML5 rules, since the `style` attribute, when used inside `body`, must appear at the start of its parent. The context is changed, and the markup is turned to HTML5-conformant, if “foo” is removed or moved after the `style` element.

Answer (score 2):

`style` only runs in the `head` of the document, simple as that. Either run an external stylesheet or include it in your html file during dev. stages.